# Jacobian with zero eigenvalues - Fixed points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, fixed-point-theorems, jacobian

I'd like to ask, if possible, for some good and not excessively long material about classification of fixed points in which the Jacobian has zero eigenvalues.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: A negative eigenvalue of the Jacobian matrix means the system is stable about that point, positive means unstable. So a zero eigenvalue means it is neither of these and the system needs further analysis. It's difficult to say anything else generally. The specifics will vary widely from problem to problem.

Comment: @K.defaoite thank you so much! I need to know more about which analysis could I do to classify these points, do you know the more commom? Many thanks!

Comment: Personally, I would say plotting the vector field is the best way to get a good idea about how the system behaves there. If the system is higher dimensional and this isn't really possible then I would say running a few simulations with a starting position near this critical point might give you some useful insight as well.

Comment: @K.defaoite thank you so much, maybe you could post the two comments as an answer!